# Search and replace in htm files

Tags: html

I am a technical writer and in the process of importing our content (HTM) into a new platform (Still HTM format). During this process I also want to use Prettyphoto to give users the ability to click on screenshots to vew a bigger version.
I have this now in my html code:

```
<a rel="prettyPhoto" href="images/xxxxxxx"><img src="images/23456.png" class="screenshot" alt="some alt text" />
```

There are thousands of files and each file could have many such images in them. where the name of the image changes but the href="images/xxxxxxx is the same

I need the xxxxxxx for each instance to be replaced by the png filename 23456.png or whatever that may be.

Is there an easy way to do this and how?

Thanking all in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for that. The function loops all items with the class `screenshot`. Read the `src` property and puts that in the parent `href`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.screenshot').each(function () {
            $(this).parent().prop('href', $(this).prop('src'));
        });
    });
</script>
```

However this is no SEO friendly. If you want the href to be available in the source you are gonna need a server side solution with some programming.